# Testing a Non-blocking Queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, testing, queue, nonblocking

I've ported the non-blocking queue psuedocode [here](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/research/synchronization/pseudocode/queues.html#nbq) to C#. The code below is meant as a near verbatim copy of the paper.

What approach would you take to test the implementation?

Note: I'm running in VS2010 so I don't have CHESS support yet.

Edit:

I've removed the code in question so some unsuspecting developer doesn't use it -- it required quite a few changes to get it bug free... and I still wasn't 100% confident that it was bug free. With brute force testing I could not get it to perform better than a lock based solution.

Also, since I'm targeting 3.5 I thought I was SOL with the 4.0 concurrent queue. The 3.5 RX framework includes a ConcurrentQueue so this was indeed just a fun little programming exercise and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VS 2010 and .NET 4, you can use [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

Comment: the question was how to test their implementation.

Comment: Yes, but if the port is avoidable, and you can get a good, tested implementation for free, it'll avoid the reason for the question entirely...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm targeting .NET 3.5. I actually took a look at their .NET 4.0 implementation in reflector and the queue in question takes a completely different approach; it's the algorithm Joe Duffy recommended in his Parallel Data Structures article...

Comment: @jsw: This, btw, is also included for .NET 3.5 in the Rx Framework, and available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Answer (score 2):

when i tried to create non-blocking queue i tested queue this way. i created 10 threads and concurrently called Enqueue 1000 times. At the end i checked size of queue, it was != 10 000. Or sometimes it threw exceptions. Then i tried concurrent deques. Same result. This clearly means that queue is not thread safe.